# Element inserted with jQuery doesn't appear right away

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a loading message while some stuff is loading, but it doesn't appear until after the stuff loads. Here is my code:

```
$('#loading').text('Loading...').show();
//alert('test');
for ( var i in ['list','of','things'] )
{
    // dummy loop to waste some time
    for ( var j=0; j<5000000; j++ ) {
        var asd = j+123*j%17;
        var qwe = j+123*asd%17 + j;
        var zxc = j+123*asd%17 + j*zxc;
    }
}
$('#loading').hide();
$('#content1').html('<ul><li>Test</li><li>Test</li></ul>');
```

When running this, the page appears blank while the for loop is running and the loading banner doesn't appear. When loading is done it simply appears and instantly starts fading out. (I added a big for loop inside the above loop to simulate a slower load and it still doesn't show the loading message until the loop is done.)

The loading takes less than a second (on Chrome, anyway) so it's not a huge problem, but why does this happen, and can I get the message to appear *before* the delay?

EDIT: updated code an put version on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/an2Pc/3/

Comment: Is it possible to give the full code? Or to make a jsfiddle? So we can try it out, and look what's wrong.

Comment: is this loading via ajax? or is it just a loop. You could always hide the data container you are loading. Statically just put the loading div in the html without using jquery. So loading will show, then once the loop is done, show the data and hide the loading div container.

Comment: are you running this code inside a `$(document).ready(function () {});`?

Comment: @Dnns, done: http://jsfiddle.net/an2Pc/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a static message, you don't need to create on the fly. Simply put it in and hide it using `display: none;` in css. Then, you can show it using `$('#loading').show()` or even `$('#loading').fadeIn()`. I don't know what do you do in the loop, but there should not be a reason for not showing inmediately.

Edited: I could verify you are right, it doesn't show, not sure why. Anyway, you can fix it by inserting the code as a callback of the show() method, it works:

```
$('#loading').text('Loading...').show(function() {
    for ( var i in ['list','of','things'] )
    {
        for ( var j=0; j<5000000; j++ ) {
            var asd = j+123*j%17;
            var qwe = j+123*asd%17 + j;
            var zxc = j+123*asd%17 + j*zxc;
        }
    }
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('#content1').html('<ul><li>Test</li><li>Test</li></ul>'); 
});
```

Edited for new case: for adding a callback to a method that doesn't include one, you can use the trick of animate some property that doesn't change anything, like this (I don't know if it's a best practice, but it works :)

`<div class="notice" id="loading">Testing</div>`

`<div class="content" id="content1">a</div>`

```
$('#loading').text('Loading...').animate({ opacity: 1 }, function() {
    for ( var i in ['list','of','things'] )
    {
        for ( var j=0; j<5000000; j++ ) {
            var asd = j+123*j%17;
            var qwe = j+123*asd%17 + j;
            var zxc = j+123*asd%17 + j*zxc;
        }
    }
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('#content1').html('<ul><li>Test</li><li>Test</li></ul>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it still doesn't show. Sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/an2Pc/3/

Comment: thanks, that works for showing/hiding elements. But it doesn't work if you just change the text of something (there is no callback function). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hi~ Please use it in your page:

```
<div class="notice" id="loading" style="display:none">Loading...</div>
<input type="button" onclick="Load()" />
```

following code in head block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Load() {
        $("#loading").css("display", "block").fadeIn('slow');
        for ( i=0; i<1000;i++) {
            // load some stuff here
        }
        $("#loading").fadeOut('slow');

    }
</script>
```

Don't forget to include the JQUERY file:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the loop to run when the page loads, not on the click of a button.  Also, `$("#loading").css("display", "block").fadeIn('slow');` is redundant, `$("#loading").fadeIn('slow');` will work fine.

Comment: This still has the same issue, where the show/hide happens after the loop is done. http://jsfiddle.net/an2Pc/5/

Comment: @Rocket: it's a misunderstanding, and very thanks for your remind me about the css in JQuery~ useful! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happens, but a solution is to the put the loop inside a `setTimeout` to delay it a bit.

```
$('#loading').text('Loading...').show();
setTimeout(function() {
    for (var i in ['list', 'of', 'things']) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 5000000; j++) {
            var asd = j + 123 * j % 17;
            var qwe = j + 123 * asd % 17 + j;
            var zxc = j + 123 * asd % 17 + j * zxc;
        }
    }
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('#content1').html('<ul><li>Test</li><li>Test</li></ul>');
}, 1);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/an2Pc/4/